$g^{\star}$ undefined terms in papers on geometric mechanics
I have been struggling for a long time to figure out the meanings of certain, related undefined terms in related papers on discrete geometric variational integrators.
One example comes from Reference [KM], where the authors define $\textrm{ad}_\xi\eta$ as a Lie bracket and $g$ as a member of a Lie group $G$, but then write $\textrm{ad}^{\star}_\xi\mu$ and $g^{\star}$ in Equation 4a:

where $\mu$ is in the co-tangent Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}^\star$, and I know what that is.
I am foxed by the star superscript on $\textrm{ad}^{\star}_\xi\mu$ and $g^\star$. The star is not a complex conjugate because these terms are not complex numbers. It's not a transpose because elsewhere the authors use a superscript $T$ for transpose. It's not an adjoint (probably?) because adjoint is defined without the star -- or is it? It's not a Hodge star because these terms are not differential forms -- or are they?
Another example is from reference [LL], wherein Equations 16b and 16c have an undefined term ${T^k}^{\star}$, where $T^k$ is defined as a member of the Lie group $SE(3)$. Again, I know it's not a complex conjugate, transpose, not obviously an adjoint, and not obviously a Hodge star. I've written the authors, who acknowledge that ${T^k}^{\star}$ is not defined, but I have not received a satisfactory answer about what it is.

It's obvious that these authors do not feel the need to describe the star, but I've been stumped for so long that I must ask for help.
My objective is to do numerical calculations, so I need to know concrete representations of these terms as arrays. I know such array representations for $g$, $\textrm{ad}_\xi\eta$, and $T^k$, and it would be ideal to know how to write array representations of the starred forms in terms of the known array representations of $g$, $\textrm{ad}_\xi\eta$, and $T^k$, but I shall be grateful for any deeper leads or other advice about how to figure them out.
EDIT: perhaps superscript star is a pullback?
[KM] Marin Kobilarov and Jerrold E. Marsden, Discrete Geometric Optimal Control on Lie Groups, IEEE Transactions on Robotics, Vol. 27, No. 4, August 2011.
[LL] Jeongseok Lee et. al, A Linear Time Variational Integrator for Multibody Systems, https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02898
